# Generate classes from xsd and rename including getters/setters

Tags: java, kotlin, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate class files from xsd files in Java 11. Part of the schema used is:

```
  <xs:element name="OptionList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Option" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="StatusCode" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

When I generate the code using a plugin from

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.0</version>
```

It creates it all in one file like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "option"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "OptionList")
public class OptionList {

    @XmlElement(name = "Option", required = true)
    protected List<OptionList.Option> option;

    public List<OptionList.Option> getOption() {
        if (option == null) {
            option = new ArrayList<OptionList.Option>();
        }
        return this.option;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "description"
    })
    public static class Option {

        @XmlElement(name = "Description")
        protected String description;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Code", namespace = "urn:schema:common:v1", required = true)
        protected String code;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "StatusCode", namespace = "urn:schema:common:v1")
        protected String statusCode;

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String value) {
            this.description = value;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String value) {
            this.code = value;
        }

        public String getStatusCode() {
            return statusCode;
        }
        public void setStatusCode(String value) {
            this.statusCode = value;
        }

    }

}
```

I am needing the classes split into multiple files. I tried adding localScoping="toplevel" as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.1"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

This generates the Option object as a separate classes but the issue remains that OptionList elements and getters/setters still reference the OptionList.Option instead of the new Option object. **Is there a way that I can get these completely split apart on generation and reference the generated class?** The ideal files generated would be these:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "option"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "OptionList")
public class OptionList {

    @XmlElement(name = "Option", required = true)
    protected List<Option> option;

    public List<Option> getOption() {
        if (option == null) {
            option = new ArrayList<Option>();
        }
        return this.option;
    }
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "description"
})
public static class Option {

    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    protected String description;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Code", namespace = "urn:schema:common:v1", required = true)
    protected String code;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "StatusCode", namespace = "urn:schema:common:v1")
    protected String statusCode;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String value) {
        this.description = value;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String value) {
        this.code = value;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(String value) {
        this.statusCode = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it might be worth explaining _why_ you need the classes in multiple files. It might help somebody to understand your problem more accurately.

Comment: Is it permitted to re-arrange the XSD fragment in the question? If so you can un-nest the `Option` element so it is at the same level as the `OptionList` element.

Comment: @kimbert They need to be split in multiple classes because I need all of the package names before the class to be lowercase. I am getting errors because of this.

Comment: @andrewjames It is possible to re-arrange the XSD fragment and I will do that if needed but I am trying to avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out a way to do this as wanted. I ended up modifying the original xsd instead to make it fit my needs.